# Confusion of using size classes in xcode 6

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6, size-classes

I'm new in using size classes and am so confused about it. In a new storyboard project, the size classes checkbox is defaultly checked and set to wAny hAny. I right clicked the main.storyboard and see the source code,I see "width="600" height="600"",which is as expected. then I switch back to interface builder,and change it to wCompact hRegular,and look into the source code,it still shows width="600" height="600", and that confused me.Shouldn't it be width="400" height="800"? Is there something i missed? Thank you advance.

Comment: you have not posted your error messaege here . so its dificult to tell what you have missed . i would like to suggest this tutorial http://swiftiostutorials.com/using-size-classes-xcode-6/. please check the steps and do .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It's my fault, I went the wrong direction on the problem I came across. But the tutorial gave me huge help, so thank you very much!